# How do I tighten up the space between the bullet and the text in a list and save it in the Bullet Library?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I believe there is too much space between the bullet and text when I apply bullets to a list of text with the Bullet Library button. Since applying bullets to text appears to also apply a hanging indent at the same time,  I’ve been able to tighten up the space by changing the  amount of space after the hanging indent in the Paragraph dialog.
I can’t figure out how to save this in the Bullet Library so I can apply it with one click and don’t have to adjust paragraph hanging indent spacing every time. Define new bullet only sets the Bullet character and Alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the MultiLevel List Dialog to attach your bullets to styles

Then, use the style to apply the bullet, not the bullets dialog/menu. The only way to modify the indents in a way that is stable is through this dialog. You can set the exact space for both the tab setting and the hanging indent in that dialog.

This is discussed and instructions are given in Word MVP Shauna Kelly's [page on controlling bullets in Word](http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html).